# Return true if 2 values exist in 1 array PHP

Tags: php

Is there a way to check if in_array exist 2 values ?

example:

```
$data = array('York','Jersey','John','Doe');

if(in_array($data == 'York') && in_array($data == 'Doe'))
{ 
       echo '2 Values from conditional in array'; 
}elseif(in_array($data == 'York')){ 
       echo echo '1 Value from conditional in array'; 
}elseif(in_array($data == 'None')){ 
       echo echo 'No Value from conditional in array'; 
}
```

Comment: `in_array('York', $data) && in_array('Doe', $data)`

Comment: you can just search for in_array method into manual http://au2.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: I asked because i have missed this part :(, thats not mean that can be down vote for that. but naa, peoples...

Answer (score 1):

It's not how `in_array` works, read manual [**in_array**](https://www.php.net/in_array) for right syntax,

```
if(in_array("York",$data) && in_array("Doe",$data)){
    //Your code goes here
}
```

Comment: I asked because i have missed this part :(, thats not mean that can be down vote for that. but naa, peoples...

Answer (score 1):

[See php official documentation](https://www.php.net/in_array) ;)

the correct syntax is `in_array('what you re looking', $the_array)`:

```
$data = array('York','Jersey','John','Doe');

if(in_array( 'York', $data) && in_array('Doe', $data))
{ 
   echo '2 Values from conditional in array'; 
}
elseif(in_array('York', $data) || in_array('Doe', $data))
{ 
   echo echo '1 Value from conditional in array'; 
}
else
{
   echo echo 'No Value from conditional in array'; 
}
```

**EDIT:** one of the multiple solution to answer to your comment...

```
function both_values_exists($array, $val1, $val2)
{
  
  if(in_array($val1, $array) && in_array($val2, $array))
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

$data = array('York','Jersey','John','Doe');
$res = both_values_exists($data, 'John', 'Doe');
var_dump($res); // true
```

Comment: But this still does not answer my question because the condition is to have the 2 values in the condition, if is only 1 of them need to return FALSE.

Comment: the main problem was the wrong usage of the function `in_array` but see my comment for one solution (but there is a lot of different ways to do the same thing)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$data = array('York','Jersey','John','Doe');

if(in_array('York',$data) && in_array('Doe',$data))
{ 
   echo '2 Values from conditional in array'; 
} else if(in_array('York',$data)){ 
       echo echo '1 Value from conditional in array'; 
} else { 
       echo echo 'No Value from conditional in array'; 
}
```

Read [in_array](https://www.php.net/in_array).